# Listbox return wrong value in WordPress 3.9

Tags: javascript, customization, tinymce

I have already created listbox for WordPress 3.8 but it's not working in new version WordPress 3.9. So I write the JavaScript code:

```
(function() {
var ICONS;
var icon = function(id) {
    return '<i class="fa fa-' + id + '"></i>';
}

ICONS = ["rub", "ruble", "rouble", "pagelines", "stack-exchange", "arrow-circle-o-right", "arrow-circle-o-left", "caret-square-o-left", "toggle-left", "dot-circle-o", "wheelchair", "vimeo-square", "try", "adjust", "anchor", "archive", "arrows", "arrows-h", "arrows-v", "asterisk", "ban", "bar-chart-o", "barcode", "bars", "beer", "bell", "bell-o", "bolt", "book", "bookmark", "bookmark-o", "briefcase", "bug"]

var menuval=[];
for (var i = 0; i < ICONS.length; i++) {
    var _id = ICONS[i];
    menuval.push({text: icon( _id )+' '+_id, onclick: function(){setcontentfun(_id)} 
  });
}

tinymce.PluginManager.add("font_awesome_glyphs", function(editor, url) {
    var menucreate=editor.addButton('fontAwesomeGlyphSelect', {
        type: 'listbox',
        text: 'Icons',
        icon: false,
        values: menuval
    });
});

function setcontentfun(id) {
    alert(id);
    return false;
}
})();
```

So, it creates the listbox and displays well, but, when I click on the menu item, it alerts last element of "ICON" array, where it displays all the elements in the listbox well. So, how can I alert the list item, which I clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after long research I find out solution,

```
var menuval=[];
var insertVar = function (val) {
    return function () { 
        editor.insertContent(val);
    }
};
for (var i = 0; i < SHORTCODES.length; i++) {
    var _id = SHORTCODES[i];
    var _code = SHORTCODE_EXE[i];
    var variable = insertVar(_code);
   //alert(_id+' '+ SHORTCODES[i]+' '+SHORTCODE_EXE[i]);
    menuval.push({text: _id, onclick: variable }); 
}
```